# Shopware 6: Query country states using the store api

Tags: api, shopware

I want to query country states via the store-API (https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/store-api-guide/sales-channel?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/store-api-guide)
In the documentation I don't see anything regarding countries, but I have the following reference: GET /store-api/v3/context gives

```
{
    ...
    salesChannel: {
        countries: [
            {
                ...
                state: null
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, this doesn't include the country states...

Shopware Version 6.3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GET /store-api/v3/country?associations[states][]` endpoint.